# PHP function to sort through a list of css styles and arrange them in groups

Tags: php, css, arrays, function, sorting

I'm stuck trying to create a function in PHP and I need help from you guys.

I need to find a way of splitting all CSS lines into arrays, and then finding the matching items and pushing them into groups. It's a bit confusing to explain so I will write this down below.

===========================================================

First -> (Standard CSS)

```
.className1 {
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.className2 {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
}

.className3 {
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.className4 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

So now lets say you push a HTML button to sort the CSS, I would like a PHP function to return back this CSS but organized and sorted, like this:

===========================================================

Second -> (What I need)

```
.className1, .className2, .className3 { color: #000; }

.className1, .className3, .className4 { text-align: center; }

.className1 { font-family: 'Helvetica'; }

.className2 { font-family: 'Arial'; text-align: left; }
```

===========================================================

This is what I have so far (Please excuse the best practices)

```
$source = $_POST['source'];

$source_lines = preg_split("/}/", $source);
$source_lines = array_filter(array_map('trim', $source_lines));

function contains_CSS_Style($str, $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if (stripos($str,$a) !== false)
        {
            $same_array[] = $a;
        }
    }
    return array($str, $same_array);
}

foreach ($source_lines as $value) {
    $selection = explode('{', $value);
    $css_name = $selection[0];
    $css_line = $selection[1];
    $css_line = str_replace(':', ':', $css_line);
    $css_style = explode(';', $css_line);

    foreach ($css_style as $style) {
        $all_styles[] = $style;
    }
}

$myArray = array_filter(array_map('trim', $all_styles));
$myArray = array_unique($all_styles);

foreach ($source_lines as $value) {
    $name = contains_CSS_Style($value, $myArray)[0];
    echo "yes! " . $name . "</br></br>";

    foreach (contains_CSS_Style($value, $myArray)[1] as $value) {
        echo "the word is ==== " . $value . "</br>";
    }

    echo "</br>";
}
```

This is what is echoed out.

```
yes! .className1 { font-family: 'Helvetica'; color: #000; text-align: center;

the word is ==== font-family: 'Helvetica'
the word is ==== color: #000
the word is ==== text-align: center

yes! .className2 { font-family: 'Arial'; color: #000; text-align: left;

the word is ==== color: #000
the word is ==== font-family: 'Arial'
the word is ==== text-align: left

yes! .className3 { color: #000; text-align: center;

the word is ==== color: #000
the word is ==== text-align: center

yes! .className4 { text-align: center;

the word is ==== text-align: center
```

If you guys can help me do this i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: ugg, if i had to edit the css of this site, the first version would be MUCH easier. I suspect it world parse faster also

Comment: Why oh why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'd just be searching for an existing CSS parser that might put the data in a format that you can work with. Otherwise, you're going to have to build your own text parser first.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: @GaryB Please update your question with additional information (i.e. code) instead of putting it in comments.  As you can see, it is rather difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: @GaryB edit the original question to add your code. Code in comments like that is unreadable.

Comment: Ah, sorry guys, one sec

Comment: Why not use one of the CSS preprocessors?

Comment: @GaryB Given your example input, what is the result of your current code?

Comment: Here it is in online executable form, as copied from the question: https://ideone.com/Y4p3AM

Comment: @PatrickQ Just added the output in the question, cheers

Comment: As suggested by other folks you should use any existing CSS pre-processor that approximates your expected results so you may go modify it tot your exact requirements.If you don't want to go that lane, I would suggest that first parse your entire input and put them in an array (like parse hashmap) indexed by the selector (with trimming) .`$a['className1']=["font-family: 'Helvetica';","color: #000;", "text-align: center;"];`  (....)  `$a['className3']=["color: #000;","text-align: center;"];`.This would make looping and comparing very easy for you

Comment: Can you please give us an idea about the bigger picture here? Do you know that this might break your CSS depending on how you print it back out? Also, though I have no idea about the final goal here, why don't your trying using LESS or SASS to organize your CSS.